# First order model vs n-order models

Tags: bayesian, prediction, model

Plenty of different research models showed that n-order models give better results than first order models. For example, for location this is work that shows this http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2181199

I am doing location prediction. I implemented and applied Bayesian inference and see that first order models gives ~15% better results than second order model. How come this can be explained?

Is it dataset dependent or why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should depend on the dataset or the specific application. Second order (or n-th order) model need not be always better than a 1st order model. If the 15% gain is observed on the test dataset, this means the 2nd order model overfits the data in this case, hence is poorer to 1st order model in the test data.